# HQL - can i join when the association is backwards?

Tags: hql

I have:

```
class A
{
    B b;
}

class B
{
}
```

I know i can do this:

```
from A a
join a.b b
```

but what I need to do is this (pseudo-HQL, it doesn't parse, hence this post):

```
from B b
left outer join A a on a.b = b
```

I get `"Path expected for join!"` :(

I want a complete list of `B`s joined onto any `A`s, if they exist. Is this possible?

I can't use a right join because SQLite doesn't support them grrrrr

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't have

```
class B {
    @ManyToMany
    A a;
}
```

?

Comment: Yes. Its not a bidirectional relationship

Comment: Well, actually, from your question... it *is*! I suppose you could always try something like sacrificing a goat. Or mapping a native SQL query. Whatever you think best.

Answer (score 0):

HQL have "with" keyword instead of on (joins are fundamentally different then in sql)

try :

```
from B b, A a
left join a.b ab with ab = b
```

or simply:

```
from B b, A a where a.b = b
```